# Mudar background de Tab específica programaticamente

Tags: java, android

Possuo um `TabLayout` no qual crio as tabs programaticamente neste método:

```
mTabLayout.removeAllTabs();

for(int i = 0; i < list(); i++) {
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(list(i).name), false);
}

TabLayout.Tab newPlanTab = mTabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.new_plan_tab);
mTabLayout.addTab(newPlanTab, false);
```

Nesta última tab que eu adiciono, eu quero setar um background e cor de texto diferente para destacá-la, porém não estou conseguindo acessar estas propriedades. Como posso fazer isso?

**EDIT**

Uma solução que eu encontrei foi usar um `CustomView`, mas não tenho certeza como customizar essa `CustomView` pra ficar igual as outras apenas com o BG diferente, ela deve herdar de quem?

Comment: O TabLayout, por acaso vai trabalhar em conjunto com um ViewPager? Se sim, existe uma forma bem fácil de fazer, inclusive você não vai precisar nem ficar criando/removendo tabs por conta própria.

Comment: Nao @MárcioOliveira , quando uma aba é selecionada ocorre uma requisição para baixar informações que são modificadas no mesmo fragment, simplesmente trocando os dados mostrados na tela.

Comment: Ué, ainda sim você poderia usar ViewPager para carregar dados diferentes num mesmo Fragment (só que em instâncias diferentes). Estou falando isso porque ViewPager + TabLayout é quase como se fosse uma coisa só, rs, então existem métodos nativos para atualizar o TabLayout conforme certas características do ViewPager. Ex: nome das abas, quantidade de abas, etc. Por exemplo, o Chrome implementa um ViewPager e adiciona abas dinamicamente.

Comment: Eu entendo o que voce esta dizendo, mas o que eu quero é mudar o background de apenas uma aba. A implementação do resto eu já fiz e está funcionando, isso seria apenas a cereja do bolo.

Comment: Você quer setar um destaque diferente do que já é criado no estilo do TabLayout?

Comment: Sim @MárcioOliveira, porque vai ser uma aba pra criar uma nova aba. Eu conversei com um colega que é Senior na área e a única solução que ele lembrou era usar customView mesmo, mas queria fugir disso se possível.

Comment: Isso que eu ia comentar. Nativamente acho que não dá.

Comment: Tente criar um tema para essa custom view tendo o "TextAppearance.Design.Tab" ou "Widget.Design.TabLayout" como pai e coloca um atributo de background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ninguém teve nenhuma ideia diferente, mesmo conversando com pessoas que trabalham comigo em Android, tive que implementar minha solução utilizando `CustomView`

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/lightBlueDefault"
        android:id="@+id/tab_plan_new_textview"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Java

```
View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.tab_plan_new, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_plan_new_textview);
textView.setText(R.string.new_plan_tab);
TabLayout.Tab newPlanTab = mTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view);
mTabLayout.addTab(newPlanTab, false);
```

Uma vez que a CustomView não preenche toda a altura da Tab, acabei optando por apenas trocar a cor do texto.